# How are <article> and <section> tags different from <div>? Do they affect anything?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Are the `<article>` and `<section>` tags important on a website, as opposed to regular `<div>`s? What is the their purpose?

For example:

- Are there any additional limitations on them? E.g. is this a correct page structure?

  ```
  <body>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h6>00/00/0000 - 00:00</h6>
      <figure>
          <img src="" alt="">
          <figcaption><b></b></figcaption>
          <hr>
      </figure>
      <div>
          <p></p>
          <img src="" alt="">
          <figcaption><b></b></figcaption>
          <hr>    
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
          <div>
              <iframe></iframe>
          </div>
      </div>
  </body>
  ```
- Do they influence search engines (as best known atm, of course) or anything else on the page?

At the moment, I don't use these tags and I would like to know the importance of it and how to use them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 tags like `<article>` and `<section>` are called [*semantic elements*](https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_semantic_elements.asp) (or *semantic tags*). Their purpose is to create a better standardization for website structures.

For example, an `<article>` tag should ideally contain an article of some kind, such as a blog post or news article. A `<nav>` tag should contain a page's navigation menu.

Using these tags instead of `<div>` tags will not change the look or layout of a page unless your browser/useragent applies different default styling to them.

Additionally, semantic tags *may* affect a page's [search engine optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization). As far as I know, there is no definitive proof yet that Google or other search engines treats pages with semantic tags differently/better than ones without them.

Comment: I read what was in the link that you gave me. According to what I understood, I made some changes to my code but I'm not sure if this is correct, could you tell me if the structure is right? https://pastebin.com/q9w7Sdvr and https://pastebin.com/SG4x4pHj

Comment: Yes. Semantic tags are meant to replace `div`s, so as long as you use them logically, as you have, you're good to go.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Comment: @Susi: If you want to get a review of your HTML, you can ask a question on [codereview.se].

Comment: @Susi: I would suggest to ask this in a question here on Stack Overflow (if you wonder what’s technically valid/required) or on Webmasters (if you wonder what search engines need).